# How to create and refer to anchors in SSRS, Report Designer or Report Builder

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I've done this numerous times in XHTML but I am not sure if it is possible to do in SSRS Reports: I am trying to create a (link) list that allows a user to click on and be moved to another point WITHIN that same report. Is this possible to create anchors and do this just like you would in XHTML? Thanks a lot!

**(tools that are available to me are SSRS in BIDs 2008 environment as well as Report Builder 3.0)**

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible.  It sounds like you would be better off embedding the report into a web app and doing it that way.

Comment: @SonnyChilds , thanks a lot for the suggestion but that's not a viable option for me. The reports are opened with Internet Explorer though..

Answer (score 3):

You could use bookmarks.

First you add bookmarks to the points in your report you want a user to be able to jump to. Select the report item you want to jump to and in the properties pane find the Bookmark property and type a unique name in here for the bookmark.

Then add a Textbox or Image that the user would click on to take them to that bookmark.  In Design view right click on this item and select the Properties option.
In the properties window select Action from the left hand side.
Choose Go to bookmark then in the Select bookmark box type the name of your bookmark that you created earlier.

OK this and you should be good to go.

Comment: "Bookmark" was indeed what I was missing. i kept searching for "anchors". Thank you so much for the answer, I wish I could vote it up except I don't have enough "reputation".